# On Focus in Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am checking for the browser compatibility for my project. I am calling a function on  the `OnFocus` event  of a button. That code is getting executed for all others browser except in Chrome, but if I call the same function on the `OnFocus` event of a text field  means that is getting executed in Chrome as well. Can anyone help me to resolve  this issue? How to call a function on the `onfocus` event of a button (which should execute in Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on monitoring the `focus` event using two methods: via `addEventListener` function and via `onfocus` element attribute.

```
<script>
function onfocused(ev){
 document.getElementById('si').textContent=ev.target.id;
}
onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('einput').addEventListener('focus', onfocused, false);
 document.getElementById('ebutton').addEventListener('focus', onfocused, false);
};
</script>

<div id=si>?</div>
<br />
<br />
Via addEventListener:
<input id=einput type=button value="einput" />
<button id=ebutton>ebutton</button>
<br />
<br />
Via onfocus attribute:
<input id=iinput type=button value="iinput" onfocus="onfocused(event)" />
<button id=ibutton onfocus="onfocused(event)">ibutton</button>
```